# Calling a SQL Stores Procedure with single input parameter in VB6

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, vb6, adodb

I'm trying to call an SQL Stored procedure in VB6 that has a single input parameter. Basically the VB6 application hands over a vendor number and it checks the status of invoices for that vendor number, and if the status = A then it returns a false value, anything else returns a true value. I have my Stored Procedure working in SQL, but I cannot get it to work when I call it in my application.

Here is what I have so far.

This is for my button click:

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command 
Public dc As New DataConnection 

Private sub btnCheckStatus_Click()
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command 
    cmd.ActiveConnection = dc
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[CheckStatus]" 
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@VendorNumber", adInteger, adParamInput, "6", VendorNumber) 
    cmd.execute 
BalanceStatus = cmd(result) 
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
```

I can't seem to get the results out of the stored procedure, I tried to set it to a variable but it will not work, it gives me a type mismatch error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to set up a Recordset to hold all of the information and assign it to my status variable.

```
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Public dc As New DataConnection   

                Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
                    cmd.ActiveConnection = Connection.dc.conn
                    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
                    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[CheckStatus]"
                    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("VendorNumber", adInteger, adParamInput,6, VendorNumber)

                Set rs = cmd.execute

                If Not rs.EOF Then
                    BalanceStatus = rs.Fields(0)
                End If
```